# Whether I can set field's comment in the Model?

Tags: django, django-models

You see the MySQL tables in the Sequel Pro, every field has a Comment:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Whether I can set the field comment in the Model?

```
class Account(models.Model):

    balance = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=1, default=1) # whether there is a property for us to set field comment?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set comment on a field in django (please check [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13867) issue)

> I understand the idea, but I'm afraid it doesn't have a good
>   usefulness/noise ratio.
>
> The ORM doesn't aim at providing a Python interface for every feature
>   of the supported database engines. Its goal is "just" to provide an OO
>   API.
>
> Since there's neither a clean API proposal, nor a patch, nor a
>   convincing explanation of the value added by this feature, I'm going
>   to close this ticket.

PS: you can use django [raw sql queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/) and manually set the comment.

Answer (score 1):

As I've [answered in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58689190/624066):

- Ticket #13867 is now "superseded" by [#18468](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18468), which was *reopened* and is now **accepted** and waiting for patches. The original rejection, after discussion on the mailing list, changed to

> I think we could implement that feature. (Yes I changed my mind from six years ago when I wontfix'd the ticket.)

- A partial solution, for PostgreSQL databases, is published at https://github.com/vanadium23/django-db-comments, as a post-migration hook Django app. Should not be hard to adjust it for MySQL databases.